# How to transpose a list of CGPoints into a Swift array

Tags: arrays, swift, transpose

I have a (list) of CGPoints returned in the format below (with line feeds ("/n") on each line):

```
80.0 (return)
100.0 (return)
120.0 (return)
150.0 (return)
```

I wish to transpose the above `CGPoint` (Doubles) (list) into a Swift (Integer) array `[80,100,120,140]` using this Swift statement: `Array(arrayLiteral: list)`:

But first I must convert the line feeds (return `"/n"`) to commas (`","`) using this Swift RegEx statement below, which is not working for some reason:

```
let wantedList = list.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: ",",options: .regularExpression)
```

Any suggestions where:

a) I am screwing up in this RegEx conversion?
b) Some way to do a one-pass transposition to get the desired array of `CGPoints` in the form of `[80,100,120,140]`

Clarification:

Many thanks: worked like a charm when passing in the raw CGPoints between a string literal (""") ! In my particular case: I am passing in my CGPoints in the form of a string variable: *let list = "(frame.origin.y)"*). I cannot figure out how to insert the required double quotes at the beginning and end of this *list* variable so I keep getting back each CGPoint as an individual array i.e. [80][100] rather than as a fully populated array `[80,100,120,140]`.

Comment: this is not a RegEx...

Comment: That doesn't seem like a list of points, but rather a list of doubles.

Answer (score 1):

You can split your string into lines and compact map the substrings up to the first space trying to initialize a Double:

```
let string = """
80.0 (return)
100.0 (return)
120.0 (return)
150.0 (return)
"""
```

---

```
let values = string.split(whereSeparator: \.isNewline)
    .compactMap { 
        Double($0[..<($0.firstIndex(of: " ") ?? $0.endIndex)])
    }
print(values)  // "[80.0, 100.0, 120.0, 150.0]\n"
```

---

If you would like integers instead of Doubles just try to find a period instead of a space:

```
let integers = string.split(whereSeparator: \.isNewline)
    .compactMap {
        Int($0[..<($0.firstIndex(of: ".") ?? $0.endIndex)])
    }
print(integers)  // "[80, 100, 120, 150]\n"
```